# modrewrite or php rewrite for language subdirectories

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

i want an .htaccess rewrite

so /en/home pulls /home
/es/stuff.php pulls /stuff.php
/fr/something/thisis.php pulls /something/thisis.php

without it being visible in the url.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*) $2 [L,NC]
```

If you want to store the current language as a query-string value, try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*) $2?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If you use the second method, you can access the language in PHP like so:

```
$language = (preg_match('/^[a-z]{2}$/i', $_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^/.{2}/(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will remove all 2 letter first directories